# Error 0xc000000e (blue Windows Recovery screen) after running Memtest86

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bsod, repair

I recently reformatted my PC.

Since then I had started randomly experiencing memory usage spikes, to the point where the PC would become unusable. I figured I might have damaged the RAM, so I ran Windows Diagnostic and it found no problems.

When looking at the logs in the Event Manager, I noticed that the memory usage spikes were happening around the same time a group of errors were detected. If I remember correctly, this thing called something like CLSID was being prevented from running because it lacked permission(s). I found a tutorial online to fix this which suggested modifying the ownership of two RegEdit entries to Administrators and then granting Administrators full control.

Since I was still concerned that some of my RAM might be going haywire, I downloaded Memtest86 and ran it until completion. After pressing escape to reboot the PC, I ended up encountering a blue 'Windows Recovery' screen with the error code '0xc000000e' which supposedly means either something is wrong with the boot record or a required device is inaccessible.

- I tried executing 'Startup Repair' via the Windows installation media, but it responds with a vague error that states 'Startup Repair couldn't repair your PC'.
- I also tried the 'Reset this PC' option while selecting 'Keep my files', which throws the error 'The drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again.'
- I tried 'Go back to the previous build' which states 'We ran into a problem  and won't be able to take you back to the previous build. Try  resetting your current build instead (Troubleshoot > Reset this PC).'
- I tried 'System Restore' which throws the error 'To use System Restore, you must specify which Windows installation to restore. Restart this computer, select an operating system, and then select System Restore.' However, I am never given  the option to select an operating system and I am not even dual booting...
- Via command prompt I also ran 'chkdsk /r' which did not fix the issue.
- I tried running all of the 'bootrec.exe' commands and all of them were completed successfully except '/rebuildbcd' which threw the error 'The requested system device cannot be found.'
- I just tried running 'sfc /scannow' and, although the verification phase completed, it is saying 'Windows Resources Protection could not perform the required operation.'

I am thinking of maybe replacing the SATA cable.

Other than that, I am not sure what to do at this point. I have months of work on that drive, which I had not yet copied to my other drives as a backup, so I do not want to reformat the drive entirely.

**Does anybody know what's happening to my PC OR how to fix this?**

Comment: Wow, you really did a lot of stuff that probably really messed things up. You’re running Windows 10, and it was probably booting on modern hardware in UEFI mode. In order to boot your memtest disk you had to change your bios settings to legacy mode. Windows won’t boot like that. All you had to do was change it back to UEFI mode. But there’s no telling what’s messed up now.

Comment: @Appleoddity But when I switched to UEFI mode, none of my drives were detected...

Comment: @Appleoddity Also, I don't see how much of what i've done would mess anything at all up. It's all basic troubleshooting, especially the few things that did successfully execute...

Comment: UEFI / Legacy mode has nothing to do with the detection of hard drives. So, you would need to be more clear where you are expecting to see a drive listed. Would you be referring to your boot order menu?

Comment: @Appleoddity You've misunderstood my comment. When I switched to UEFI mode, no drives were listed explicitly, yet in UEFI/Legacy mode the drives are listed explicitly. Anyways, I switched to UEFI mode and chose Windows Boot Manager and now it's working... :/ How do you imagine I messed up my PC? Which things that I did would have messed up my PC and how??